# Update column based on DateTimeIndex from date range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe with a DateTimeIndex and an empty column called HOLIDAY.

I want to set the value of that column to 'YES' if the datetime in the index is on a holiday, so that the resulting dataframe is like this:

```
TIME                    HOLIDAY
2019-11-25 06:00:00     NO
2019-11-26 21:00:00     NO
2019-11-27 18:00:00     NO
2019-11-28 08:00:00     YES
2019-11-29 08:00:00     NO
2019-11-30 08:00:00     NO
```

I have a list of dates:

```
holidays = ['2019-07-04', '2019-11-28','2019-12-25']
holidays = pd.to_datetime(holidays)
```

I tried this, but I get an error:

```
df.loc[df.index.date.isin(holidays), 'HOLIDAY'] = "YES"
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

- `holidays` contains a.o. `2019-11-28` **at midnight**,
- your DataFrame contains a.o. also `2019-11-28`, but at **8:00**.

If you want to find rows with index values in `holidays` dates (regardless
of the time part), you have to "nullify" the time part.

One of methods to get the rows in question is to use **boolean indexing**:

```
df[df.index.floor('D').isin(holidays)]
```

The result is:

```
                    HOLIDAY
TIME                       
2019-11-28 08:00:00     YES
```

You can also get only `HOLIDAY` column, running:

```
df[df.index.floor('D').isin(holidays)].HOLIDAY
```

This time the result (*Series*) is:

```
TIME
2019-11-28 08:00:00    YES
Name: HOLIDAY, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTimeIndex.date returns a numpy array of strings not pd.Series of pd.Timestamp dtype.  So you must get the same dtype on both sides of the equality:

If TIME is not in your index this will work:

```
m2 = df['TIME'].dt.date.isin(holidays.date)
```

or

```
m2 = df.index.to_series().dt.date.isin(holidays.date)

df.loc[m2, 'HOLIDAY'] = "YES"
```

Output:

```
                    HOLIDAY
TIME                       
2019-11-25 06:00:00      NO
2019-11-26 21:00:00      NO
2019-11-27 18:00:00      NO
2019-11-28 08:00:00     YES
2019-11-29 08:00:00      NO
2019-11-30 08:00:00      NO
```